# A box contain 5 balls. and the balls have marks, 1\$, 5\$ and 15\$.

Tags: probability

I am a little confused with this exercise, can someone review this?

A box contains 5 balls. and the balls have marks, 1\$, 5\$ and 15\$:

- Two balls have the mark 1\$
- Two balls have the mark 5\$
- One ball have te mark 15\$

A game consists in paying 10\$ for winning the sum of the balls. For example, if I have 1 ball 5\$ and one ball 15\$, then I win 10\$ $((15+5-10))\$$.

Calculate the expected value.

**My work**

Let $X=-8,0-4,6,10$. Let $p$ a probability function. Then

$$p(-8)=1/10$$
$$p(-4)=4/10$$
$$p(0)=1/10$$
$$p(6)=2/10$$
$$p(10)=2/10$$

Then,

$E[X]=-\frac{8}{10}-\frac{16}{10}+\frac{12}{10}+\frac{20}{10}=\frac{8}{10}$

Is the reasoning good?
Thanks for all.

Comment: How many balls can you select, two?

Comment: yes, only two @callculus

Comment: Your thoughts, probabilities and the expected value are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternative working for the setting of drawing with replacement:

First we have to pay $\$10$, hence $-10$,

Also, for each draw, the expected mark is $\left(\frac{2\cdot 1+2\cdot 5+15}5 \right)$

$$2 \cdot \left(\frac{2\cdot 1+2\cdot 5+15}5 \right)-10=\frac{54}{5}-10=\frac45$$

which agrees with your solution.

Comment: Thanks, very glad for your answer.